# Why the compiler can't capture the wildcard in this case

Tags: java

I am reading an wildcard example in wildcard capture and helper methods in The Java tutorial. I don't understand why the compiler produces a capture error when compiled:

```
import java.util.List;

public class WildcardError{

    void foo(List<?> i){
        i.set(0, i.get(0));
    }
}
```

Why does the compiler processes the iinput as being of type object?

Comment: What input? What indication do you have that it handles the type `Object` here? What error does the compiler give you?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the List is some `List<E>` and `i.get(0)` does return an `E` and the question is: why does the compiler complain about incompatible types when calling `i.set(int,E)`?

Comment: @assylias Right, for i.set(0, i.get(0)), the compiler required: int, CAP#1 but it found: int, Object

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis The tutorial says that the compiler processes the i input parameter as being of type object, but I don't know why.